# For await x of y using an AsyncIterator causes memory leak

Tags: node.js, typescript, memory-leaks, async-await, iterator

When using AsyncIterator i have a substential memory leak when used in for-x-of-y

I need this when scraping a HTML-Page which includes the information about the next HTML-Page to be scraped:

1. Scrape Data
2. Evaluate Data
3. Scrape Next Data

The async Part is needed since axios is used to obtain the HTML

Here is a repro, which allows to see the memory rising von ~4MB to ~25MB at the end of the script. The memory is not freed till the program terminates.

```js
const scraper = async ():Promise<void> => {
    let browser = new BrowserTest();
    let parser = new ParserTest();

    for await (const data of browser){
        console.log(await parser.parse(data))
    }
}

class BrowserTest {
    private i: number = 0;

    public async next(): Promise<IteratorResult<string>> {
        this.i += 1;
        return {
            done: this.i > 1000,
            value: 'peter '.repeat(this.i)
        }
    }

    [Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterator<string> {
        return this;
    }
}

class ParserTest {
    public async parse(data: string): Promise<string[]> {
        return data.split(' ');
    }
}

scraper()
```

It looks like that the `data` of the for-await-x-of-y is dangling in memory. The callstack gets huge aswell.

In the repro the Problem could still be handled. But for my actual code a whole HTML-Page stays in memory which is ~250kb each call.

In this screenshot you can see the heap memory on the first iteration compared to the heap memory after the last iteration

[Cannot post inline Screenshots yet](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/385901951881052161/634788315903557676/unknown.png?width=1256&height=674)

The expected workflow would be the following:

- Obtain Data
- Process Data
- Extract Info for the next "Obtain Data"
- Free all Memory from the last "Obtain Data"
- Use extracted information to restart the loop with new Data obtained.

I am unsure an AsyncIterator is the right choice here to archive what is needed.

Any help/hint would be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In Short

When using an `AsyncIterator` the Memory is rising drastically. It drops once the Iteration is done.

The `x` in `for await (x of y) is not freed till the Iteration is done. Also every Promise awaited inside the for-loop is not freed.

I came to the conclusion that the Garbage Collector cannot catch the contents of Iteration, since the Promises generated by the `AsyncIterator` will only fully resolve once the Iteration is done.
I think this might be a Bug.

#### Workaround Repro

As workaround to free the contents of the Parser we encapsulate the Result in a lightweight Container. We then free the contents, so only the Container itself remains in Memory.
The `data` Object cannot be freed even if you use the same technic to encapsulate it - so it seems to be the case when debugging at least.

```js
const scraper = async ():Promise<void> => {
    let browser = new BrowserTest();

    for await (const data of browser){
        let parser = new ParserTest();
        let result = await parser.parse(data);
        console.log(result);

        /**
         * This avoids memory leaks, due to a garbage collector bug
         * of async iterators in js
         */
        result.free();
    }
}

class BrowserTest {
    private i: number = 0;
    private value: string = "";

    public async next(): Promise<IteratorResult<string>> {
        this.i += 1;
        this.value = 'peter '.repeat(this.i);
        return {
            done: this.i > 1000,
            value: this.value
        }
    }

    public [Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterator<string> {
        return this;
    }
}

/**
 * Result class for wrapping the result of the parser.
 */
class Result {
    private result: string[] = [];

    constructor(result: string[]){
        this.setResult(result);
    }

    public setResult(result: string[]) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public getResult(): string[] {
        return this.result;
    }

    public free(): void {
        delete this.result;
    }
}

class ParserTest {
    public async parse(data: string): Promise<Result>{
        let result = data.split(' ');
        return new Result(result);
    }
}

scraper())
```

#### Workaround in actual context

What is not shown in the Repro-Solution is that we also try to free the Result of the Iteration itself. This seems not to have any effect tho(?).

```js
public static async scrape<D,M>(scraper: IScraper<D,M>, callback: (data: DataPackage<Object,Object> | null) => Promise<void>) {
        let browser = scraper.getBrowser();
        let parser = scraper.getParser();

        for await (const parserFragment of browser) {
            const fragment = await parserFragment;
            const json = await parser.parse(fragment);
            await callback(json);
            json.free();
            fragment.free();
        }
    }
```

See: https://github.com/demokratie-live/scapacra/blob/master/src/Scraper.ts
To test with an actual Application: https://github.com/demokratie-live/scapacra-bt (`yarn dev ConferenceWeekDetail`)

#### References

- Github NodeJs: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30298
- Github DEMOCRACY: https://github.com/demokratie-live/democracy-client/issues/926

#### Conclusion

We found a feasible Solution for us. Therefore i close this Issue. The followup is directed towards the Node.js Repo in order to fix this potential Bug

> https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30298